# How to use localStorage value filter in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I've set a value when the user click vote choice. Its working.

```
.then(function(response) { 
  localStorage.setItem('isClicked', 'Yes');
  var i = +localStorage.key("nid");
  var nidId = 'nid' + localStorage.length;
  localStorage.setItem(nidId, vm.nid);
  vm.clickedBefore = true;
})
```

This is my HTML scope:

```
<div class="card myfunc" ng-repeat="myfunc in myfuncPage.myfuncs" id="{{myfunc.nid}}"  >

  <div class="item item-text-wrap">
    <h2 class="item-icon-left"><i class="icon ion-ios-analytics"></i>
      {{myfunc.title}}</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-text-wrap" ng-show="localstorage">
      <img ng-src="{{myfunc.field_image.und[0].imgPath}}"/>
      <p class="custom-class" ng-bind-html='myfunc.body.und[0].value'>
      </p>
      <ul ng-repeat="vote in myfunc.advmyfunc_choice">
        <li ng-repeat="voteselect in vote">
          <div class="row">
            <button class="col button button-outline button-dark" ng-click="myfuncPage.sendNid(myfunc);myfuncPage.sendVote(voteselect);showVoted = ! showVoted" >{{voteselect.choice}}</button>
            <div class="voted-screen" ng-show="showVoted">
              <h3>Thanks.</h3>
            </div>      
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </div>
```

In basically, I need remember the div via localStorage and when the page refresh, hide choice divs.

`ng-show="showVoted"` working on click but I need on refresh.

What is the best way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what local storage module you are using, so I can't be specific, but I would write factory that handles the retrieval and storage of the values you need

```
(function () {
  var voteFactory = function (localStorage) {
        return {
            getVote: function (key) {
               var isVoted = false;  

               // get local storage item, set voted etc
               var voted = localStorage.getItem(key);
               if(voted) {
                  isVoted = voted;
               }
               return isVoted;

            },
            setVote: function(key, value) {
               localStorage.setItem(key,value);
            }          
         };
       };
      app.factory('voteFactory', ['localStorage', voteFactory]);
 })();
```

Then within the scope controller/directive you are using to show or hide you would have a function:

```
$scope.showVoted = function(key) {
  return voteFactory.getVote(key);
}
```

then ng-show="showVoted(theidentifieryouwantouse)"

It is also worthwhile to mention I would use ng-if instead of ng-show. To be more efficient you could store your votes as an array instead of individual values and do a check to see if you have retrieved all values, get from local storage if not.  Then your functions would interrogate retrieved array instead of repeated calls to local storage.  I would also advice maybe using a promise in the factory because retrieval from local storage could be delayed causing some ui oddities.

Hopefully this is along the lines of what you are looking for.  I can elaborate if needed.